# Audio attachment with image in android

Tags: android, audio

I have image is my Draw able folder.When I call this image I want to play an audio also which is in my raw folder.can I do this how??please help me.

Comment: I have some images of comic when I called one image i want some music or audio file also should play..can it happen??

Comment: try to play audio when you call the image

Comment: @kshma ya you can do it useing countDownTimer. i know your requirement

Comment: so please explain it..How to use counter

Comment: how to play audio.when calling image

Comment: first tell me are you want to implement like training that show image first and play audio of that and after some time load second image and sound?

Comment: if you not get me response then not getting any help from my side

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by creating image button and put image on it. and onClick of that button you can play the music using MediaPlayer api.

Refer this : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html

Example code for Play audio from Raw folder 
           : http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/06/android-development-audio-playback-safely/

Comment: no i dont want bitton or somthing else..I just want to play audio when image page is calling.automatically

Comment: Put play audio call in onCreate method of image page. does it answer your question ?? if not..Please provide some more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

you can write this code at onResume:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.raw.name);
                mp.start();
                while (mp.isPlaying()) { // donothing
                }
                ;
                mp.release();
```